# Modify Each Div Separate of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show elements by the select option value of each `div.wrap`. 
Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/na9rbdyo/1/

```
<div class="wrap">
<select id="type">
    <option default value="0">-- Select One --</option>
    <option value="1">Hot</option>
    <option value="2">Cold</option>
</select>
<div class="hot">
    This is hot!
</div>
<div class="cold">
    This is cold!
</div>
</div>
```

Basically there will be multiple divs with the same structure. The user can use the select box to select an option(hot and cold for demo purposes) if the users selected cold then only the div `.cold` will show.

Each select option should only effect the `.wrap` div that is in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. when you select Hot or Cold from the menu what do you expect to happen. also the fiddle is nice but you should include the code here as well

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the parent of the select control that is changing, and then find the div with the matching class that will be show, something like this:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var selectedTxt = $(this).find(':selected').text().toLowerCase();            
    $(this).parent('.wrap').find('div').css('display','none')     
    $(this).parent('.wrap').find('div.'+selectedTxt ).css('display','block');

});
```

Comment: this is a nice solution as well

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications I've got it working

First never have more than one element with the same id this will cause problems

so I changed them to classes

I also add a little be of css

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select class="type">
        <option default value="0">-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="1">Hot</option>
        <option value="2">Cold</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hot">
        This is hot!
    </div>
    <div class="cold">
        This is cold!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <select class="type">
        <option default value="0">-- Select One --</option>
        <option value="1">Hot</option>
        <option value="2">Cold</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hot">
        This is hot!
    </div>
    <div class="cold">
        This is cold!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hot,
.cold {
    display: none;
}

.display {
  display:block;
 }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.type').change(function(){
   var select_val = $(this).val();
    var wrap = $(this).parent();
    if(select_val == 1){
        $('.hot', wrap).addClass('display');
        $('.cold', wrap).removeClass('display');
    }else if(select_val == 2 ){
        $('.cold', wrap).addClass('display');
        $('.hot', wrap).removeClass('display');
    }
});
```

and 
[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xy817uq9/1/)